# Specify asset image for UIImageView for all devices

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiimageview

Is there a way I can say for a particular UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *imageView = <#instantiate#>
imageView.image = @"someImageFromImageAsset";
```

and based on the device it's rendering on, it sets the right image. Obviously I need to set the image for a particular device but I am unsure how you do it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

iOS will automatically choose the correct sized image if you just use the name of the image. Use @2x in the image file name for retina display.

Objective-C

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"someImageName"];
```

Swift

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "someImageName");
```

Comment: Small issue - in asset image, how do I specify image specifically for iPhone 5s/6/6 Plus?

Comment: iphone 5/5s/6 are all considered "@2x". 6 plus uses the "@3x" designation. However, you can append special designations if you want to have specific assets for each. You will need to write a helper method that determines your phone version and loads the correct image.